# How do I apply transactions to TypeORM when using it in activerecord mode?

Tags: transactions, typeorm, typeorm-activerecord

I'm using TypeORM in active record mode and I wanted to apply transactions. In particular, I wanted each of my tests to be wrapped in a transaction, so, achieving something like this:

```
beforeEach(async () => {
  // start transaction
})

afterEach(async () => {
  // rollback transacttion
})

test("create new", async () => {
  // create new
}
```

So, I tried this:

```
let queryRunner: any

beforeEach(async () => {
  queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner()
  await queryRunner.connect()
  await queryRunner.startTransaction()
})

afterEach(async () => {
  await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
  await queryRunner.release()
})

test("Create user", async () => {
  let user = new User()
  await user.save()
})
```

but it looks like those transactions are started on a separate context/connection, because after the test runs, I can see the record in the database.

How do I make the transaction affect the user being saved?

Answer (score 1):

`instance.save()` will use another `queryRunner` see [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/51b2a63d91d4e6a935e83f47fb958f4867e82e9c/src/entity-manager/EntityManager.ts#L314),
this means it doesn't use the transaction you started, therefore you can't rollback `user.save()`;

When you call `user.save()` `COMMIT` is called, you can check this by setting `logging: true` in the connection options.

You should run the `save` using the `queryRunner` you created, this way you can rollback

```
test("Create user", async () => {
    let user = new User()
    await queryRunner.manager.save(user);
})
```

Comment: Yeah, but that isn't using the activerecord-like `save()` method.

Comment: To comply with the Active Record pattern you could create you own save method within 
the model and passe the queryRunner `saveWithTransaction(queryRunner)`.

If you want to control the transaction you must use the queryRunner. 

With `Sequelize` for example you can run `instance.save()` under a transaction by passing a transaction in the options 
object of `save()`, with `Typeorm` it's just a boolean to enable/disable 
wrapping the persistence operation into transaction.

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to connect your query runner to the db. Try to modify your code as follows:

```
let queryRunner = getConnection().createQueryRunner()
await queryRunner.connect()
await queryRunner.startTransaction()
let user = new User()
await user.save()
await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction()
await queryRunner.release()
```

Also, you should use try-catch-finally block.

Comment: I just tried that, same issue. The records are present in the database after the test run.